# Is there a way to use DI inside Expression.New()

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, expression

I'm trying to add some DI to code that contains:
`Expression.New(newType)`

I currently have a  `IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver` which resolve or return null if a service is set.

I would like to know if there is any way to get an expression which will basically do the equivalent of `dependencyResolver.Resolve<NewType>() ?? new NewType()`

I already tried something like :

```
expr = expr !=null ? expr : Expression.New(typeof(NewType))
```

But obviously it doesn't work well because the expression is never null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do pass parameters to the constructor? If you are making an ioc container it's much more complicated than it may look.

Comment: trying to add DI to an mapper framework that doesn't support it currently. for the moment i need to explicitly specify for each of my object that i want the mapper to try DI resolve before executing the mapping default constructor

Comment: Ok well then, if dependencyResolver is existent during the execution of the expression(after the code gets compiled at runtime) you should just execute that method and not use the Expression new. If you can't access the dependencyResolver you won't be able to new up objects by your self because of the context problem since dependencies can have different scopes.

Comment: This is a red flag to me. Mapper libraries (like AutoMappee) are meant for mapping simple data-centric objects. Those objects should not get dependencies injected into them during their construction. My experience is that designs like these cause all sorts of complications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an method overload of `Expression.New` that accepts an params array of `Expression` that describe the constructor arguments of the type. By supplying the correct `Expression` objects for each argument, you will be able to create the correct expression tree that is able to create types with overloaded constructors.

For instance:

```
var resolverExpr = Expression.Constant(resolver, typeof(IDependencyResolver));
var getServiceMethod = typeof(IDependencyResolver).GetMethod("GetService");

var constructor = typeof(NewType).GetConstructors()[0];

var constructorArguments =
    from p in constructor.GetParameters()
    select Expression.Call(
        instance: resolverExpr,
        method: getServiceMethod,
        arguments: new[] { Expression.Constant(p.ParameterType, typeof(Type)) });

var newExpr = Expression.New(constructor, constructorArguments.ToArray());
```

Comment: This might not work depending on when this expression is build. If for example this is done during application start up the IDependencyResolver won't be able to resolve anything in the HTTP request scoop. If you do it on per call basis the original http scoop will be used on every call. For situations like this its better to pass it as a parameter to a lambada function. Also there is no need to call new when you can getService the NewType and it will do this for you.

Comment: @Filip all good points, and I can myself add many more limitations and quirks in my answer. I built Simple Injector, so I actually do know a thing or two about DI and constructing expression trees. I would say this code is: don't try this at home.

Comment: Agreed this all sounds like a bad idea as I mentioned building an IOC container is a difficult thing to do right. My guess is that there is probably a simpler solution to the issue or he missed some constraints why this is necessary. In any case it's probably better to resolve the services during expression building and pass it as a constant rather then keeping the whole resolver as a reference.

Comment: wanted to make it more generic for other people to use the mapper framework but as it seems to be kindof anti patern ;) i may just keep my way to do it which is basicly doing it from my code and not from the framework itself. Thanks for all those detailed ideas